# Foundation 5 visibility classes not working on table row

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, visibility

I'm using foundation visibility classes to show/hide table rows and cells based on the screen size.

I'm using the foundation-rails gem directly from github.

I use the following code to show and hide a full width td:

```
[...]
/* Should show up only on small screens */
<tr class="hide-for-medium-up">
  <td colspan="4">
    No entries found!
  </td>
</tr>
/* Should show up only on medium and larger screens */
<tr class="hide-for-medium-up">
  <td colspan="4">
    No entries found!
  </td>
</tr>
[...]
```

I've tried and tried but it is simply not working. **When I resize the row with the class "hide-for-medium-up" behaves correctly - hiding on a small screen. But the first row does not do that - it should show up on a small screen and be hidden for the rest.**

I've checked out the CSS with chrome inspector and it seems as if the class that would be hiding the row  is overridden by another one.

Here's a screen shot (Inspector @ Screenwidth of 1100px (i.e. large screen)):

[image: Inspector @ Screenwidth of 1100px (i.e. large)]

Why is this happening? I have disabled all other css classes but the effect is still the same.
I have tried many other classes as "show-for-small-only" and so on...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check for the computed property in the chrome inspector tool. You should find the exact line which over-rides your code

Comment: It seems like Foundation did this on purpose.  The same thing happens if you go to Foundation's own site and try to insert a table.

Comment: Alright so it might just be a bug in the package. I see that someone has opened an issue on github already after I posted this question. https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/5766